# Problem converting Array to Arraylist for dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, types, arraylist, dataprovider

```
private var MealsListResult:ArrayList = new ArrayList;
protected var _data:resultData = new resultData;

private function resultHandler():void
    {   
    var Meals:Array = _data.Meals;
    MealsListResult = _data.Meals as ArrayList;
    MealDataGrid.dataProvider = Meals;
    MealListView.dataProvider = MealsListResult;
    }
```

Should this be working?  the MealDataGrid is populating based on the array, but I am debugging and MealsListResult is null. but _data.Meals is not and I dunno if I'm missing something simple.

I can get it to work by doing it like: `var MealsListResult2:ArrayList = new ArrayList(Meals);` but I feel as though the first method *should* be working as well!

(there's mxml list and datagrid and such not shown here of course)

Comment: May I ask, why ArrayList rather than ArrayCollection? I've never used ArrayList myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if `_data.Meals` is its runtime type is an array then `_data.Meals as ArrayCollection` will failed. but, `new ArrayCollection(_data.Meals as Array)` will working fine.

**CMIIW**
i guess your problem is you can't use single object as 2 or more different ui dataprovider.

try to use

```
MealDataGrid.dataProvider = _data.Meals;
MealListView.dataProvider = ObjectUtils.clone(_data.Meals);
```

**UPDATE:**

sorry i miss readed, i though it was ArrayColletion. but all you need to do is the same like ArrayCollection

Comment: Using new ArrayList(_data.Meals as Array) passes in an Array as the source Array for the ArrayList - thats the correct way of doing it. The ArrayList is just a 'wrapper' for an Array, that why casting it using 'As ArrayList' wont work. Same with ArrayCollection